# videos editing in android, insert and remove frames from video

Tags: android, video-editing

I've been working on this videos thing in android and I thought to make it more functional. I have a question that, is there any way we can insert or remove frames from some video, like edit videos the same way we edit images, give them effects and all. I think, I am clear. Any links, sample codes, hints or books would be useful to start with this.
thanks :)

Comment: any point to suggest ? found anything about it?

Comment: You can use javacv wrapper for android https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Answer (score 0):

Here are multiple things you can look for video editing.

The more efficient in FFMpeg android sample for processing video (so that effects on video applied and saved on device as new video with applied effects) [FFmpeg android java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/)

For run time effects, just to show the user effect on video while running in your app, can use [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/news/2013/0529/19.html)